# Create a post automatically if search result has zero results

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, posts, search, query-posts

I'm developing a site where people can search phone number(s), the most complex part is that i want to create a post automatically when someone search for a specific number if that phone number yield zero results want to create a post with title as the searched number. this should be done without any user registration process. is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just a word of caution here, this has the potential of taking your site down. If your site is flooded with searches, you'll be creating a lot of posts. What is the intent behind this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the standard WordPress search, you can get the searched number with `get_search_query`

So this code will create a new draft post if no results were found for the search:

```
        $match = get_page_by_title( sanitize_title( get_search_query() ), OBJECT, ['post_type' => 'post'] );
        if ( empty( $match ) ) {
            wp_insert_post(
                ['post_title' => sanitize_title( get_search_query() ) ]
            );
        }
```

The above snippet would be added to the `search.php` template in your theme.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll try.

Comment: This might not work as expected as the search term could also be in the post content. I'll update the answer later unless someone else does

Comment: Please shed some more light, will this save the post as draft or?